# Дефис в иностранных словах

Tags: орфография

Дело вот в чем. Есть некое название, записанное по-русски испанское слово "las noches" (ночи). Но как в данном случае правильно будет написать: Лас-Ночес или Лас Ночес? С дефисом или без?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Единых правил для транслитерации иностранных названий не существует, лучше всего постараться найти словарную или картографическую фиксацию.
По аналогии с "Лос-Анджелес", "Лас-Пальмас"  и т.д. могу предположить, что дефис уместен.